# How do I decide when to write a directive or just global css classes in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

Assuming I have a situation when we want to enchant some of our html with a nice reusable css style I have two options:

- I can write a css class that is available globally and add the class to the element or
- I can write a directive which will encapsulate the css, however that directive will do nothing more than add css to the HTML tag

In which situations should I use the first solution and in which the second?

Answer (score 1):

If CSS can do what you want, I would stick with CSS. If you need more flexibility that is hard to achieve with CSS alone I would try to make it work using a directive.

Comment: Actually, the way the css is inserted into the DOM if you're using the `styleUrls` property of your component is somehow disturbing. it pollutes the DOM with inline style tags in the `head` section and adds attributes to all your targeted html elements which are then used as selectors in the style declarations. Its super comfortable, but i dont like it and i wonder about performance.

Comment: When the soon to be released offline template compiler is used performance shouldn't be affected.